# Routing in play! framework based on database information

Tags: java, routes, playframework, multi-tenant

I'm using play! framework 1.2.5 for a multi-tenancy application. Tenants are resolved on domain base and are kept as Models. There are multiple types of tenants, that don't share all of the functionality the applicaiton provides, so controllers are organized in packages, namespaced by their corresponding tenant types.

Now I try to map some urls to variable target actions, defined by the currently active tenant, without passing the tenant's namespace inside the url.

I know that it is possible to execute scripts inside of play's routes file, so I'm wondering if there's any possibility to pass tenant information (thus database information) to the routes file.

Do you know any way how to do this?

And if not:

How can I realize routing approach without providing extra namespace information and without re-inventing play's request parameter binding?